# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access

Tags: angularjs, symfony, http-headers, cors

I have an application in AngularJS (ionic framework), and a server in Symfony.

In local everything works, but now I do my tests with the server online. Unfortunately everything does not happen like local, I have the following error:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http: // localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

I was wondering how to add the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" CORS header that is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this bundle: [NelmioCorsBundle](https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioCorsBundle)

The CORS-Bundle is used to define the CORS rules. This bundle allows you to define which domains will have access to your REST API. And it will make your job easier too :)

Comment: Yes thank you very much ! I was just trying to test this bundle, and it works :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your issue came from Angular, it looks like it comes from your API server.

You may need some headers server side:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
```

Comment: Yes I say to myself the same thing now that you make the remark to me. So I have to look for a way to add the headers to the Symfony server